# Reading Excel sheet with filters

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I want to read an Excel sheet in Python 2.6, on which some filters have been applied. I only need to read the data that would be visible with the filters on.
I have tried xlrd, but `sheet.nrows` give the entire count of rows. I also read about the `Rowinfo.hidden` option, but can't get it in this version (0.9.4). Also, not sure if `formatting_info='True'` might help, but when tried, it says `formatting_info=True not yet implemented`.

How can I use the `RowInfo` class?

I see a parameter named `hidden` in it.

Comment: loop over the rows in the sheet and skip if `Rowinfo.hidden ==1` ?

Comment: Not sure what this means as 0.9.4 is the current version of xlrd and `Rowinfo` class should be supported: *but can't get it in this version (0.9.4)*

Comment: @DavidZemens can you demonstrate how the `Rowinfo` class can be used?